# I'm stuck on Step 70 of HOJYO Takashi's Buddha... what does the diagram mean?

Tags: origami, yoshizawa-randlett

I'm stuck on Step 70 of [Hojyo Takashi's Buddha](http://origami.gr.jp/~hojyo/103buddha.html) (the one in the 6th Tanteidan Convention book), and I don't read Japanese:

[image: Tanteidan 6th Convention diagram for Step 70 of Hojyo's Buddha]

Clearly, from Step 71, I'm pulling paper around to cover the front of the wrist, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to flip the paper around and leave the rest of the hand the same.  What am I missing?

Addendum:

Closeup of the Japanese text for the Step 70 description:

[image: Step 70 text close-up]

Doing Japanese OCR, hand-fixing the scanos, and running it through Google translate has been *no help at all.*

Comment: You might consider chatting with the users in the Japanese learners chat room. They could probably give you an actual translation since some of them are relatively fluent. Look for snail plane, one of their mods.

Comment: I can read Japanese and I've done some origami, but unfortunately some of those kanji are just too fuzzy to make out. Any chance of getting a higher resolution picture of the text?

Comment: @Ixrec  Added. Hope it helps!

Comment: Have you finally lost the mystery ? I also had this challenge and never solved it.

Comment: @Ariel, not yet!

Answer (score 4):

As you found yourself Google Translate was not particularly helpful in this matter:

> By overlaying the more because What is the other side
>
> ` Ru to one representing the thumb of muscle
>
> To SenWataru and ho stick base of Ne亢layers of trout
>
> Although a state of twisted without breaking the non- g was Li
>
> Only to cowpea in the following figure around the hand of Saki珊
>
> Become good long as )

And using the camera-based Google Translate, we get:

> To represent the muscles of the thumb by overlaying more flipping and to the opposite side (but better at the root of this layer is to state that twisted without breaking the perfect interfere with the base looks like the following figure only the peripheral of the hands of the tip it is sufficient)

[I approached the users in Japanese.SE chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29942772#29942772) for help with this. This is a wiki since the work was done by [broccoli forest](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/7810/broccoli-forest) who is a user over there. It was translated as:

> roll up a layer and cover up opposite side with it so that visualize thumb's muscle

Note though, by that users admission, he is not familiar with origami.